# Should protected questions prevent the comment privilege from the association bonus?

Tags: discussion, comments, protected-questions, association-bonus

At 1 rep, a user can post, i.e. ask a question or post an answer to a question. They must earn sufficient rep to be able to comment.

Users with the association bonus get 100 points added, so a new user can post and comment.

Protected questions prevent users with only the association bonus from posting. They have to earn sufficient rep on that site. However, they are still allowed to comment, and post answers as comments, defeating the purpose of protecting the question.

Should protected questions block commenting with only the association bonus?

Comment: What are your pro and contra arguments you want to discuss? Or are you asking if it should be that way but is broken?

Comment: Do such comments happen often enough to be a problem?